# Is this database relation schema correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made my first project and got into problem that I couldn't get the right category_information values for specific competitions category through relations. So I started thinking that this could be the wrong schema for this task, so my question - is it actually wrong?

Current Scheme:

[image]

Comment: Please, add code of your attempt. What your models look like? How do you try to get category_information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following relationships between models from your image.

```
class Competition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories
  has_many :informations
  has_many :category_informations, through: :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :competetion
  has_many :category_informations
  has_many :information, through: :category_informations
end

class CategoryInformation
  belongs_to :catagory
  belongs_to :information
end

class Information < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :competetion
  has_many :category_informations
  has_many :catagory, through: :category_information
end
```

Model can relates with one_to_many_to_many using :through option

It explains a association used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model.

you can get the category_informations from competition like

```
Competition.first.category_informations
```

It is all for doing! Pretty good, right?

And you could do get information from category too

```
Category.first.informations
```

Actually wrong schema doesn't exist, just there exists some wrong association description.

You can get more usage to use association from [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) at 2.3 section and 4.3 section

Comment: What could be the best solution for category edit- I need to show all information fields and populate with category_information (even if there is none)?

Comment: There are not different upper case.  Select a source and include associations and load them. Like this,  Category.first.includes(:category_informations, :informations).each { |category| p category.category_informations; p category.informations }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following relationships between tables,

A competition has_many categories,

A competition has_many information,

A category has_many information,

A category has_many competition,

An information has_many category

You can use has_many_through relationships

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_competitions
  has_many :competitions, through: :category_competition
  has_many :category_informations
  has_many :informations, through: :category_informations
end

class Information < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_informations
  has_many :categories, through: :category_informations
end

 class Competition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_competition
  has_many :categories, through: :category_competitions
end

class CategoryCompetition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :information
end

class CategoryInformation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :information
end
```

By this way you can access,Categories of a particular competition by @competition.categories

This article might be helpful for you to understand associations better
https://www.sitepoint.com/master-many-to-many-associations-with-activerecord/